# How to fix Android Studio NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am getting a

`NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/psi/search/NonClasspathDirectoriesScope: com/intellij/psi/search/NonClasspathDirectoriesScope`

message in `Event Log` each time I try to perform any operation after updating to Beta 0.8.3.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukwuJ.png)

I have tried searching for it but no solution. Apart from that I have no idea what that means or how it can be fixed. Is reinstalling the only option?

[Here is the full error message](http://pastebin.com/yYQCuGtM) because It is too long.

Edit: Fixed by reinstalling same version over the current installation. Kept all the plugins and project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio 0.8.3 is **not** beta, [it is in the canary channel](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio083released). Yes, I think your only option is downgrading and/or reinstalling a more stable release.

Quote from the link in case it goes dead:

> posted Jul 21, 2014, 5:03 PM by Tor Norbye
>
> We've just released Android Studio 0.8.3 to the canary channel, with the following improvements